# Windows Server 2012 - Service starting itself if stopped ?

Tags: windows-server-2012

I´m a newbie on Windows Server and i´m trying to understand a behavior that a couple of users have described on a workstation.

They claim that a java program that is installed as a service is auto starting itself after 10 minutes when the the users stop it.

The Service is configured as Auto-Start and according to users, if the service is set to "Manual" then the auto starting behavior will stop.

I did a little research and didn´t find anything related to configuring a service to auto start when it is stopped (only when it fails)

Could anyone explain if that´s a valid behavior for a service ? 
This "auto start service when stopped" is a configurable service option?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a scheduled task that is automatically restarting the service if it has been stopped.  Please see https://superuser.com/questions/240067/automatically-restart-windows-service-if-it-is-not-running for an example of this.  I supposed it could also be a second service that is restarting the first if it has been stopped.

Comment: Thanks @kevin mills, what i find strange is that they claim that only when the service is stoped but set as "Automatic" the system will restart the server. I think it´s possible that maybe the server is restarting and they are not noticing it. I stopped the service for about 15 minutes and it didn´t start itself.

Comment: If you are an administrator, this may make a difference.  It could be that the user who stopped a service is queried, and if it's an admin, the service does not restart.  It would be worthwhile to check this behavior as a non-privileged user for due diligence.